# not able to update (visually) the original position of an UIView after changing its anchor point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I´m not able to show an UIView at its original position once i´ve changed its anchor point and update its position to the original one.

For example:

I have one view inside another (the main view). The view child (viewA) is at the position (110,234) and its size is (100,100).

And the following code shows the way I´m trying to change the anchor point of view A, from the default (0.5,0.5) to the lower right corner (1.0,1.0). And how I´m trying to reset the original position of view A layer, after i´ve changed its anchor point.

This code is in the viewDidLoad method of the main Viev Controller.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //the default anchor point of view A is (0.5,0.5) at the center of layer

    //show position of view A in output console
    NSLog(@"View Pos X: %f View Pos Y: %f",      CGRectGetMinX(self.viewA.frame),CGRectGetMinY(self.viewA.frame));

    //save the original position of view A according to the future anchor point (lower right corner)
    CGRect frame = self.viewA.frame;
    CGPoint originalPos = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(frame), CGRectGetMaxY(frame));

    //set the new anchor point for view A
    self.viewA.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);

    //show position of view A in output console
    NSLog(@"View Pos X: %f View Pos Y: %f", CGRectGetMinX(self.viewA.frame),CGRectGetMinY(self.viewA.frame));

    //try to restore the position of view A layer according the new anchor point (1.0,1.0)
    self.viewA.layer.position = originalPos;

    //update visually the layer of view A (i think this is not necessary)
    [self.viewA setNeedsDisplay];

    //show position of view A in output console
    NSLog(@"View Pos X: %f View Pos Y: %f", CGRectGetMinX(self.viewA.frame),CGRectGetMinY(self.viewA.frame));
}
```

But visually the view A don´t back to the original position.
And looking at the output console it seems that the view is located at the initial position.

```
View Pos X: 110.000000 View Pos Y: 234.000000
View Pos X: 60.000000 View Pos Y: 184.000000
View Pos X: 110.000000 View Pos Y: 234.000000
```

Why? What´s happening? What´s wrong in my code?

I will be very pleased if anyone can help me.